# Decreasing granularity of dropwizard Timed Jersey endpoints

Tags: dropwizard, metrics

Consider this Jersey REST endpoint annotated for Dropwizard metrics:

```
@GET
@Path("/widgets/{id}")
@Produces("application/json")
@Timed(name="widgets.read", absolute=true)
public Response getWidget(@PathParam("id") String id) { .... }
```

The library is creating named timers per url:  /widgets/foo, /widgets/bar, etc.  This is probably desirable in many cases.  However, in my scenario, I have over 60 million widgets and this behavior is consuming a significant portion of my heap.  I'd rather that the library track at the less granular /widget level.  Is there a way to accomplish this with the native metric annotations or do I need to roll my own using the core API?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it wasn't Dropwizard at fault, but the SpringBoot [MetricFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/ce2346b0878ca2a0ff77922206a1a60149aed46e/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java).  It can be disabled via:

```
-Dendpoints.metrics.filter.enabled=false
```

or

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude=MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class)
```